# Events shows wrong time in Google Calendar through api

Tags: timezone, google-calendar-api

I've created an event and also passed the `EST` timezone. But in my Google Calendar, it displays as time offset 3 hours later.

For example, I pass the values as

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-27T15:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "EST"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-27T19:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "EST"
}
```

But the values shown in the calendar is:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-27T18:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "EST"
},
"end": {
    "dateTime": "2017-10-27T22:00:00-04:00",
    "timeZone": "EST"
}
```

This is serious issue. Can anyone please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- Don't pass `EST`.  Use the full `Area/Locality` format of the [tz identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

  - While `EST` is a valid identifier, it is fixed to UTC-5.  It's really only there for certain backwards compatibility scenarios.
  - The date you gave is during daylight saving time, and is UTC-4.
  - Assuming you meant the US Eastern time zone, you should pass `America/New_York` as the time zone id.
- Even with the above taken into consideration, your output shouldn't actually be as shown above.

  - Perhaps you are just looking at the calendar and not taking the calender's time zone setting into account?
  - [See the `timeZone` calendar settings in the API docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings)

Comment: In my code, i converted my sql.timestamp to long before converting to the standard form of RFC3339. Does that change the timezone? And can we set timezone as Etc/GMT-5?

Comment: As you said, I've tried like how you said, I have set the TimeZone as "America/New_York" and I've added the event through api, still it gets added in wrong time. The calendar's timezone sets accordingly write or should i set it through api?

Comment: I've tried one more method, i didn't give timezone in start and end parameter and the event is added correctly, how does that happen?

Comment: Please edit your question to include code, otherwise I can't help you.  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: What I'm exactly asking is how to create event at 10:00 am for that particular timezone?